# what is the best way to represent hexagonal latice

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have a hexagonal latice:

```
 _   _   _
/ \_/ \_/ \_ 
\_/ \_/ \_/ \ 
/ \_/ \_/ \_/
\_/ \_/ \_/
```

What is the best way to represent it with 2-dimensional array or whatever

Comment: Are you interested in nodes or the areas?

Comment: what are you looking to represent? an infinite lattice? a finite lattice of rectangular shape? data on the vertices? data on the edges?

Comment: See [A Slanted Hexagon](http://ferkeltongs.livejournal.com/31455.html) and [Amit’s Thoughts on Grids](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/grids/)

Comment: Depends on the things @Jason listed, plus what you plan to do with it, how you want to store or access data.

Comment: I'm interested in areas. Latice is infinite. Data is in areas

Comment: what are common processes that you want to do with the data?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest way to represent a hex grid with a 2D array is to skew your axes:  each row of hexes is offset by half a step more than the previous one.  It doesn't matter whether each row is offset forward or backward, as long as you're consistent about it; below, each successive row is offset half a hex forward:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4)

   (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4)

      (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)

         (3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4)
```

It is easy to determine the nearest neighbors of any given hex: in the case above, for a given array address `(r,s)`, you have:

```
(r-1, s)
(r-1, s+1)
(r, s-1)
(r, s+1)
(r+1, s-1)
(r+1, s)
```

Also, note that drawing location is simple: the center of hex `(r,s)` above is at screen location:

```
x= dx * (s + 0.5*r)
y= dy * r
```

---

As an alternative, you could offset alternate rows by half a hex absolute.  This will give you a more rectangular shape for a given array, but determining drawing location and nearest neighbors would then require two cases, for even and odd rows respectively.

There are other coordinate systems available, but they are less convenient and more obscure...

---

Since the OP wants more, I'll add a link to my favorite obscure hex indexing system:  a ["spiral honeycomb mosaic"](http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/shm/).  This uses a base-seven system to index successively larger "super-hexagon" groups of hex locations, as follows (note that it is labeled in base-7, not base-ten):

```
7 elements:              49 elements:

  2   3
                            22  23
1   0   4  -->
                  12  13  21  20  24
  6   5
                11  10  14  26  25  32  33

                  16  15  02  03  31  30  34   --> [3 base-7 digits
                                                    -> 343 elements...]
                62  63  01  00  04  36  35

              61  60  64  06  05  42  43

                66  65  52  53  41  40  44

                      51  50  54  46  45

                        56  55
```

The link has some code for dealing with this coordinate system, but I haven't really tried evaluating it....

Comment: your solution doesn't actually represent the lattice shown in the answer - it's rotated through 90 degrees.  the question's lattice doesn't have directly horizontal neighbours, but does have vertical ones.

Comment: @andrew cooke: Really? feeling a bit picky today are we? :-) It was probably easier to draw the picture in ascii. One can certainly swap the roles of r and s and flip the picture...

Comment: I was thinking r=rows and s=skewed-columns;  C-style array convention is usually A[row][column] anyway.  Of course, as phkahler says, you can draw it however you like...

Comment: @comingstorm, thank you for your answer! An interesting thought. 2all, any other ideas?

Comment: A recent question on the GameDev StackExchange has methods for converting between Spiral Honeycomb Mosaic and the skewed axis system: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71785/converting-between-spiral-honeycomb-mosaic-and-axial-hex-coordinates (as well as links to other indexing styles)

Answer (score 3):

A 2d array is fine using 2 rows = 1 hex height, and 1 column = 1 hex width.

```
4,1,5,2,6,3
4,7,5,8,6,9
A,7,B,8,C,9
A,D,B,E,C,F
```

- Every pair of numbers is 1 hex tile.
- Finding 12 and 6 o'clock is just a +-Y until your on a different tile
- Finding 2 and 4 o'clock

  - Check if Y+1 is the same tile

    - If it is, 2 o'clock is X+1 & 4 o'clock is X+1,Y+1
    - If it is not, 2 o'clock is X+1,Y-1 & 4 o'clock is X+1

Comment: Another way to think about this pattern is: take a square lattice, and drop half the coordinates based on parity (e.g., only accept/use those coordinates `(x,y)` such that `x+y` is even).  Of course, you don't want to waste half your array entries -- thus, @LastCoder's arrangement above.

Answer (score 3):

Please be noted that, there are four different ways to represent the hexagonal lattice. I spend lots of hour searching for a solution and could not able to match one with another. And then I realize, there are 4 different ways to build and represent a lattice. So, when choosing one, make sure what format are you trying to use. The four formats are given below:

[image]
Picture is taken from: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#conversions